Remove not used sinks in ALSA
Just installed Debian 12 from scratch and Kodi, only using ALSA for sound.
I have two sound devices, the HDMI to my sound receiver and an external DAC.
Every thing runs good with great sound quality, but I got 3 HDMI connection in Kodi gui that I do not use (the first one I use even spells out name of sound receiver).
The only configuration I had done is to set index of cards in /etc/modprobe.d/sound.conf to (as it was flipped in order during reboot);
options snd_hda_intel index=0 options snd-usb-audio index=1

So how can I remove the unused HDMI sinks in ALSA, should I just edit some Kodi file, witch files to edit?
EDIT
AI chat gpt sugested adding an udev rule.
So what I did:
Created the file:
/etc/udev/rules.d/99-nvidia-hdmi.rules
With this content:

SUBSYSTEMS=="sound", ATTRS{id}=="NVidia", ATTRS{device}=="7", KERNEL=="card*", OPTIONS+="ignore_device"
SUBSYSTEMS=="sound", ATTRS{id}=="NVidia", ATTRS{device}=="8", KERNEL=="card*", OPTIONS+="ignore_device"
SUBSYSTEMS=="sound", ATTRS{id}=="NVidia", ATTRS{device}=="9", KERNEL=="card*", OPTIONS+="ignore_device"

Made it executable:
sudo chmod u+x /etc/udev/rules.d/99-nvidia-hdmi.rules
Did a reboot of machine.
But that did not function,  still the sinks in kodi  gui. Something I missed, a prefix for the card, maybee ( I tried to read about it on internet, but it is quit complicated.
Grateful for help!

"only using ALSA for sound" ? Do you mean applications input and ouput directly to ALSA devices with no use of any sound server (Pulseaudio or Pipewire or jack) ?

Yes, thats how Kodi gives best sound.
